# Page title shows "title | sitename"

Tags: drupal

I have upgraded my development site to the latest Panopoly release and now my page titles include the site name. The daftest example is the contact form, which now has the title "Contact us | sitename". I've played with various options in my panels content settings, even tried the Page Title module (I see there are issues for it in Panopoly so not surprised that hasn't worked). I find it hard to imagine it's an issue and suspect I've (unwittingly) done something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag

Change globals here
/admin/config/search/metatags/config/node

Change specific content types by:
● admin/config/search/metatags/config/add

● Select Type Dropdown: “THE CONTENT TYPE YOU WANT TO CHANGE”

○ Add and configure

*Example below using tokens
○ Page title: “[site:name] at [node:title]”